# Ошибка при отправке ajax-запроса

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core-webapi

Есть `Api`, запускается в vs 2017 `Ctrl+F5`, так же на локальном IIS есть фронтенд.
По нажатию на `Войти` должен приходить `токен`.
Проверяю в постмене - все работает:.

код `ajax` с `postman`:

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://localhost:44311/api/user/login",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "Postman-Token": "49834433-34a0-4c59-9593-8ea5bd8515b2"
  },
  "processData": false,
  "data": "{\n\t\"UserName\":\"MARS\",\n\t\n\t\"PasswordHash\":\"123qweASD!\"\n}"
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

теперь тоже самое но с ajax запроси по нажатию кнопки `войти`:

```
       $.ajax({
            async: true,
            crossDomain: true,
            url: "https://localhost:44311/api/user/login",
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "cache-control": "no-cache",
                "Postman-Token": "c236d8f2-4ef0-4187-bfea-494d032e179a",
                // "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true"
            },
            processData: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { "UserName": "MARS", "PasswordHash": "123qweASD!" },
            success: function (res) {
                alert(res);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error.");
            }
        });
```

ошибки:

```
 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44311/api/user/login' from origin 'http://localhost:5555' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Upgrade:**

Запорос:

```
$.ajax({
            async: true,
            // crossDomain: true,
            url: "https://localhost:44311/api/user/login",
            type: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "cache-control": "no-cache",
                "Postman-Token": "c236d8f2-4ef0-4187-bfea-494d032e179a",
                // "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true"
            },
            processData: false,
            jsonp: "callback",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            data: { "UserName": "MARS", "PasswordHash": "123qweASD!" },
            success: function (res) {
                alert(res);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error.");
            }
        });
```

Что в браузере:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно сделать ajax запрос???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй тип запроса сделать `jsonp`.

Ссылка на мануал - [learn.jquery.com](http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/)

```
// Using YQL and JSONP
$.ajax({
    url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql",

    // The name of the callback parameter, as specified by the YQL service
    jsonp: "callback",

    // Tell jQuery we're expecting JSONP
    dataType: "jsonp",

    // Tell YQL what we want and that we want JSON
    data: {
        q: "select title,abstract,url from search.news where query=\"cat\"",
        format: "json"
    },

    // Work with the response
    success: function( response ) {
        console.log( response ); // server response
    }
});
```

Comment: переделал, но не помогла. Только теперь запрос странный

Comment: добавил в вопрос

Comment: Ну вот скриншот не очень удачный (браузер). Надо именно ответ сервера. Попробуй еще в `data` указать `format: "json"`

Comment: проблема кроется в cors. добавил на стороне сервера `services.AddCors();` и `app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin());` но все равно ошибка `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц попробуй в PHP скрипте: `<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>` или поменять метод `POST` на `GET`. Также можно в запрос: `headers: {  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'htt://site allowed to access' },`

Comment: а зачем? Во первых серв на шарпе, ну а во вторых, если пролиснуть вопрос на картинку постмен, то там видно, что серв отдает этот хедер

Comment: Кстати уже заработало... Помогло перезагрузка всего...все было написано правильно....( Обидно что такое происходит